# Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT Does not work in my FullScreen Mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, dom-events

I'm working react.js image gallery project with [this as starter](https://reactjsexample.com/react-carousel-image-gallery-component-with-thumbnail-and-mobile-support/).
There is a `Settings` field to customize the gallery performance.
I am showing this setting on the right side of the screen when in `Full screen mode` as like as below image.

[image: FullScreen Image Gallery setting].

By the way, the 2 input elements don't work as if they were disabled. (*mouse clicking*, *typing any keyboards*), I can't do anything with these inputs.

I know that Using the Fullscreen API in web browsers, for security reasons, most keyboard inputs have been blocked in the `Full screen mode`. To fix this problem I tried use `Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT` in my code.

```
fullScreen() {
    const { useBrowserFullscreen } = this.props;
    const gallery = this.imageGallery.current;

    if (useBrowserFullscreen) {
      if (gallery.requestFullscreen) {
        gallery.requestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      } else if (gallery.msRequestFullscreen) {
        gallery.msRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      } else if (gallery.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        gallery.mozRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      } else if (gallery.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        gallery.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      } else {
        // fallback to fullscreen modal for unsupported browsers
        this.setModalFullscreen(true);
      }
    } else {
      this.setModalFullscreen(true);
    }

    this.setState({ isFullscreen: true });
}
```

But does not fixed problem. [Here is full source code git repository if you want to check current status](https://github.com/ClusterH/react-image-gallery).

Kindly use `node 10.x.x` to run successfully. and steps to see error is follow:

1. Move to `Full Screen Mode` by clicking button at the bottom of the screen.
2. Mouse Click to see the small menu.
3. Select `Setting` to show **Settings**.
4. Another properties work as well, but only does not work with `Input`.

when I'm on the `general mode`, no `Full screen mode` and follow above steps, then `Input` working fine.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `Setting Element` didn't included in `Image Gallery Element` `Dom` tree.
`Full Screen Mode` work for `Image Gallery Element`, but `Setting Element` didn't belong to tree, so does not work.

After put `Setting` to `Image Gallery`, `Input` worked properly.
[Updated git repository](https://github.com/ClusterH/react-image-gallery)